# Selenium SendKeys to JqueryUi Popup

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been having troubles with Selenium on and off for quite a while now. So, I thought I would create a nice simple example and hopefully a selenium expert can show me:

- what I am doing wrong; or
- what is wrong with the website that I am driving.

For this exercise, I have created a simple console application with a view to logging in to a library website. Obviously, username and password are not correct. But the fact is, the code which I present below cannot even type characters in a text box which is visible on the page:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"E:\");
        var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

        chromeDriverService.Port = 7788;

        var driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions);

        var nav = driver.Navigate();
        nav.GoToUrl("http://sapln.ent.sirsidynix.net.au/client/charlessturt/");

        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("#libInfoContainer > div.loginLink > a"))).Click();

        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("j_username"))).SendKeys("gfhjdskaf");

        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("j_password"))).SendKeys("gfhdsjffd");

        driver.FindElementById("submit_0").Click();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

By all means, try and populate that text box. I would love to hear how you achieve it. 
I am using:

1. v.2.43.1 of Selenium with the latest version of Chrome
2. v.2.43 of ChromeDriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your dialog is opening in an iframe. You'll need to switch to that iframe before you can interact with the login form elements.

I didn't test your code, but you can follow the example below, by removing my comments:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"E:\");
    var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

    chromeDriverService.Port = 7788;

    var driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions);

    var nav = driver.Navigate();
    nav.GoToUrl("http://sapln.ent.sirsidynix.net.au/client/charlessturt/");

    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("#libInfoContainer > div.loginLink > a"))).Click();
```

assuming your iframe is the first found you can use something like...:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe").get(0)));
```

Since your iframe doesn't have an id, we can't simply do:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("id of frame");
```

It would be super convenient if you could give your iframe an id.

Now lets continue with your code:

```
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("j_username"))).SendKeys("gfhjdskaf");

    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("j_password"))).SendKeys("gfhdsjffd");

    driver.FindElementById("submit_0").Click();
```

Once you're logged in, you need to switch back to the default content

```
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); 

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Simply inject that iframe switch before you attempt to interact with dialog, and inject the defaultContent() switch at the end before attempting to do anything else with initial page and you're good.

Good luck!

Comment: You are correct. An id would be great. That site is not my coding. I wouldn't use an iframe either. But your code is good (translated to C#)!